# Relation between two variables in a function

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have a function, say `F1[θ1_, ϕ_] = Sin(θ1 + ϕ) + Cos(θ1 + ϕ)` and another function `F2[θ2_, 2ϕ_] = Sin(θ2 + 2ϕ) + Cos(θ2 + 2ϕ).` I want to know the relation between $θ1$ and $θ2$ such that `F1[θ1, ϕ] = F2[θ2, 2ϕ]`. For all values of θ1, θ2 and ϕ.

How can I solve such type of problems on *Mathematica*?

Comment: Write it in Mathematica code `Ctrl+K` format not Latex format(so that we copy), please

Comment: These functions are identical. In general, you can solve such systems with SolveAlways, which, however, sometimes suppresses solutions. It is therefore recommended to use Reduce to crosscheck.

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: Actually I was not sure about the domain of theta1, theta2 and phi. But now I realize that I don't need to restrict these variables. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

start with reduce, and use `LogicalExpand` to give  a list of `Or` 'd expressions.

```
s = Reduce[
   Sin[θ1 + ϕ] + Cos[θ1 + ϕ] == Sin[θ2 + ϕ] + Cos[θ2 + ϕ], {θ2}, 
   Reals] // LogicalExpand
```

> (C[1] ∈  Integers && θ1 - 4 π C[1] == θ2) || (C[ 1] ∈ 
>       Integers && π/2 - θ1 - 2 ϕ -  4 π C[1] == θ2) || (C[1] ∈ 
>       Integers && θ1 -  2 (π + 2 π C[1]) == θ2) || (C[1] ∈ 
>       Integers && π/2 - θ1 - 2 ϕ -  2 (π + 2 π C[1]) == θ2)

since we are only interested in solutions that are true for all ϕ, choose the results that do not depend on ϕ:

```
 Select[s, FreeQ[#, ϕ] &]//Simplify
```

> C[1] ∈   Integers && (θ1 == θ2 + 4 π C[1] || θ1 ==  2 π + θ2 + 4 π C[1])

Its kind of annoying this doesn't simplify more, but you can see it is equivalent to the obvious answer which is `θ2 = θ1 + 2 π C[1].`

Comment: Could you tell me your email Id George? I am stuck with a problem of finding root of an equation. I tried to post it here, but I am not able to do so for some unknown reason. Could you please help me sought it out?